# which type gets used in this import statement?

Tags: typescript, vite

I am working on Vite project with a TypeScript codebase.
The code's using the OpenLayers library. This question is not specific to OpenLayers, just mentioning it for completeness purposes.

In my `package.json` I have `"ol"` as a dependency and `"@types/ol"` as a development dependency. In the code I have the following statement:

```
import GeometryLayout from 'ol/geom/GeometryLayout';
```

It is not clear to me where TypeScript reads the definition from.

Problem is that there exist three different `GeometryLayout` files at the following locations:

```
$ find node_modules/ | grep GeometryLayout | grep -v map$ | grep -v src
node_modules/ol/geom/GeometryLayout.d.ts
node_modules/ol/geom/GeometryLayout.js
node_modules/@types/ol/geom/GeometryLayout.d.ts
```

The files *all* contain different definitions:

```
$ cat node_modules/ol/geom/GeometryLayout.d.ts
declare namespace _default {
    const XY: string;
    const XYZ: string;
    const XYM: string;
    const XYZM: string;
}
export default _default;


$ cat node_modules/ol/geom/GeometryLayout.js
/**
 * @module ol/geom/GeometryLayout
 */
/**
 * The coordinate layout for geometries, indicating whether a 3rd or 4th z ('Z')
 * or measure ('M') coordinate is available. Supported values are `'XY'`,
 * `'XYZ'`, `'XYM'`, `'XYZM'`.
 * @enum {string}
 */
export default {
    XY: 'XY',
    XYZ: 'XYZ',
    XYM: 'XYM',
    XYZM: 'XYZM',
};


$ cat node_modules/@types/ol/geom/GeometryLayout.d.ts 
/**
 * The coordinate layout for geometries, indicating whether a 3rd or 4th z ('Z')
 * or measure ('M') coordinate is available. Supported values are 'XY',
 * 'XYZ', 'XYM', 'XYZM'.
 */
declare enum GeometryLayout {
    XY = 'XY',
    XYZ = 'XYZ',
    XYM = 'XYM',
    XYZM = 'XYZM',
}

export default GeometryLayout;
```

Judging from the error I am getting (`Cannot use namespace 'GeometryLayout' as a type`) I'd wager it's the `node_modules/ol/geom/GeometryLayout.d.ts` file.
How can I specifically import the `enum` type defined in the `node_modules/@types/ol/geom/GeometryLayout.d.ts` file?

My `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
   
    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

My `vite-config.ts` is:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import checker from 'vite-plugin-checker';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    checker({
      typescript: true
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: '@', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)) },
      { find: '@types', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./node_modules', import.meta.url)) },
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: If `ol` includes type definitions you don't need `@types/ol` at all. You would have been told this when installing it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ol

Comment: Did you already try adding resolve alias for `@type/ol` to your vite config file?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I uninstalled `@types/ol` and the situation is cleaner now.

Comment: @mandy8055 yeah, as you can see I have a route for `@types` in the config type but that route got me nowhere. When I forced the compiler to import the `d.ts` file from `node_modules/@types` I got the message: `Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing 'ol/geom/GeometryLayout' instead of '@types/ol/geom/GeometryLayout'`

Answer (score 0):

`ol` is a **typescript** package (blue TS mark)
[image]

That means `@types/ol` is **deprecated** for that version of the package and should be uninstalled

To find from which file the type is imported from, use `go-to-definition` on some interface prop like `req.path`

To import types you should use `ol/geom/GeometryLayout` just as it suggests to do, as

```
import type { A } from 'ol/geom/GeometryLayout'
```

if you don't need runtime import